# Inverted order of numpy array gradient and matplotlib quiver

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm using numpy 1.6 and matplotlib 1.1.1, trying to generate a velocity field from a scalar field that I have. So far, I'm generating my scalar data as such:

```
    num_samples = 50
    dim_x = np.linspace(self.min_x, self.max_x,num_samples)
    dim_y = np.linspace(self.min_y, self.max_y,num_samples)
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(dim_x, dim_y)

    len_x = len(dim_x)
    len_y = len(dim_y)

    a = np.zeros([len_x, len_y], dtype=float)
    for i, y in enumerate(dim_y):
        for j, x in enumerate(dim_x):
            a[i][j] = x*y # not exactly my function, just an example
```

Then I get the gradient:

```
   (velx,vely) =  np.gradient(a)
```

From the numpy documentation, velx is the x component and vely is the y component of the vector field. Checking the docs for matplotlib, I use quiver to plot a vector field using arrows. It states that velx and vely are the x component and y component of the vector field:

```
    fig0 = plt.figure()
    ax = fig0.add_subplot(111)
    Q = ax.quiver(X,Y, velx, vely )
    plt.show()
```

This gives the wrong result for the velocity field:

[image: Wrong result for the scalar field]

The only way of the graph looks ok is if I invert the components on quiver:

```
    Q = ax.quiver(X,Y, vely, velx )#WHY???
```

[image: Right result with the "wrong" expression]

I'm suspecting that is something like row-or-column ordering, but I can't figure it out if the output of np.gradient is inverted, or if quiver is inverted. All one dimensional problems are working as expected. Thanks!

EDIT: just to make even more clear how this is inverted, change the function

```
a[i][j] = x*y
```

to

```
a[i][j] = x*x
```

The gradient should be in the x direction, increasing with increasing x. The results are still wrong: if I use

```
Q = ax.quiver(X,Y, velx, vely )
```

I get

[image: Still wrong]

and if I invert it

```
Q = ax.quiver(X,Y, vely, velx )
```

I get

[image: Right]

Maybe there's a more pythonic (and correct!) way to do it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're right, (this is an array ordering issue).  `a` is built as `a[yidx,xidx]` but when you take the gradient, you do:  `velx, vely = np.gradient(a)` when you should be doing `vely, velx = np.gradient(a)`.  Since the gradient along the 0th axis should give you `vely` (presumably `d/dy(a) = vely`)? -- unless I'm missing something (in which case I'll happily delete this answer).

Also note that I think you can build "`a`" without the nested lists:

```
a = X*Y
```

which should work for more complicated functions as well...

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Could you please explain how I'm building my array as a[yidx, xidx]? I thought that index j, in the second for, is for the row, so x values, and vice versa? If you're right them I should invert the order in the loop, but them this gives problems with contour and contourf...

Comment: @Ivan -- Simple.  In your loops, `i` is returned when iterating over `dim_y` and `j` is returned in your iteration over `dim_x`.  Then you pack the elements in as `a[i,j]`.  Am I missing something (it's entirely possible).

Comment: You're totally right. I'm making a huge confusion with the order of the elements. I'm completely confused by what should be x == i or y ==j.

Comment: @ivan -- Generally, I've stopped thinking about `rows` and `columns`.  Those are terms which apply to matrices.  you have a 2D array, not a matrix.  For me, it's easiest to associate a given dimension with a particular axis.  By this, I mean that as I iterate over that axis, I will get slices where the axis value is constant.  I'm not sure if that description is helpful or not ...  (If it isn't, just ignore this comment).